# Implementing sql merge join on akka sources

Tags: join, akka, akka-stream

I want implement `sql merge join` for different akka streams. 
For example I have 3 classes:

```
case class A(id: String, as: String)
case class B(a_id: String, bs: String)
case class C(id: String, as: String, bs: String)
```

and I have two sources (`Source[A]`, `Source[B]` both are sorted by `id` and `a_id`) and I want get a `Sink[C]` predicated by `id=a_id`. I can't understand how cant be it implemented.

example of streams:

`Source[A]` contains: A(1, "a1"), A(2, "a2"), A(3, "a3_1"), A(3, "a3_2"), A(4, "a4")

`Source[B]` contains: B(2, "b2), B(3, "b3")

`Sink[C]` must be: C(2, "a2", "b2), C(3, "a3_1", "b3"), C(3, "a3_2", "b3")

Comment: I don't think a merge-join is possible without potentially blowing up your memory.  A left-join or right-join may work.

Comment: May be I don't write correctly, I wrote about SQL inner/left join implemented like [`Merge Join`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190967(v=sql.105).aspx) from query plan

Answer (score 0):

The example above is not correct for `OneToManyMergeJoin` spec.
Correct is:

```
case class A(id: Int, as: String)
case class B(a_id: Int, bs: String)
case class C(id: Int, as: String, bs: String)

val source1: Source[A, NotUsed] = Source(
  List(A(1, "a1"), A(2, "a2"), A(3, "a3"), A(4, "a4"))
)
val source2: Source[B, NotUsed] = Source(
  List(B(2, "b2"), B(3, "b3_1"), B(3, "b3_2"))
)
```

One of the sources MUST be DISTINCT and both are sorted by some property.
So we can use

```
class OneToManyMergeJoin[Distinct, Duplicated, O](val zipper: (Distinct, Duplicated) ⇒ O, val comparator: (Distinct, Duplicated) => Int) extends GraphStage[FanInShape2[Distinct, Duplicated , O]]  {
  override val shape: FanInShape2[Distinct, Duplicated , O] = new FanInShape2("OneToManyMergeJoin")

  private val left = shape.in0
  private val right = shape.in1
  private val out = shape.out

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes) = new GraphStageLogic(shape) with StageLogging {
    setHandler(left, ignoreTerminateInput)
    setHandler(right, ignoreTerminateInput)
    setHandler(out, eagerTerminateOutput)

    var leftValue: Distinct = _
    var rightValue: Duplicated = _

    def dispatch(l: Distinct, r: Duplicated): Unit = {

      val c = comparator(leftValue,rightValue)

      if (c == 0) {
        emit(out, zipper(leftValue,rightValue), readR)
      } else {
        if (c < 0) readL() else readR()
      }

    }

    private val dispatchR = { v: Duplicated =>
      rightValue = v
      dispatch(leftValue, rightValue)
    }

    private val dispatchL = { v: Distinct =>
      leftValue = v
      dispatch(leftValue, rightValue)
    }

    lazy val readR: () => Unit = () => read(right)(dispatchR, () => if (comparator(leftValue, rightValue) < 0) readL() else completeStage())
    lazy val readL: () => Unit = () => read(left)(dispatchL, () => if (comparator(leftValue, rightValue) > 0) readR() else completeStage())

    override def preStart(): Unit = {
      // all fan-in stages need to eagerly pull all inputs to get cycles started
      pull(right)
      read(left)(
        l => {
          leftValue = l
          read(right)(dispatchR, () => completeStage())
        },
        () => completeStage()
      )
    }

  }

}
```

as an implementation for [Merge Join](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/08/03/merge-join/) with `equals predicate`.

It can be used with first `Distinct source`, second `Duplicated source`, `zipper function` and `comparator function`:

```
def oneToManyMergeJoin[Distinct, Duplicated, O](s1: Source[Distinct, NotUsed], s2: Source[Duplicated, NotUsed])(zipper: (Distinct, Duplicated) => O, comparator: (Distinct, Duplicated) => Int): Source[O, NotUsed] = {
  Source.fromGraph( GraphDSL.create() {implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val m = builder.add(new OneToManyMergeJoin[Distinct, Duplicated, O]( zipper, comparator))

    s1 ~> m.in0
    s2 ~> m.in1

    SourceShape(m.out)
  })
}

oneToManyMergeJoin(source1, source2)( (a, b) => C(a.id, a.as, b.bs), (a, b) => Ordering.Int.compare(a.id, b.a_id))
  .runWith( Sink.foreach[C](p => log.debug(s"Sink: $p") ))
```

result:

```
DEBUG Sink: C(2,a2,b2)
DEBUG Sink: C(3,a3,b3_1)
DEBUG Sink: C(3,a3,b3_2)
```

Why I need it? One of the cases is a merging cassandra not full denormalized tables (but sorted already).